# InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1.") is throwing error in linux but not in windows

Tags: java

I am expecting UnknownHostException when I call `InetAddress.getByname("127.0.0.1.")` due to extra dot in the end.

But it is not happening in windows, where as in Linux it is throwing error as expected.

Comment: Try `127.0.0.1` instead of `127.0.0.1.`

Comment: The OP knows that the last dot is not supposed to be there and wonders why it doesn't trigger an error in Windows.

Comment: @Zoyd That's not immediately obvious from the "question" (which is just a series of statements, and never actually asks anything).

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one.  I don't have an answer (yet), but here is what I have found.

**UPDATE** - I misread the code.  Based on your comment there is a `native` method involved, and that means platform specific code.

I checked out the OpenJDK 8 code and took a look at the native method implementations:

```
jdk8u/jdk/src/{windows,solaris}/native/java/net/Inet4AddressImpl.c
```

The two versions of the code are very different, but in both cases, an attempt would be made to resolve a malformed IP address using the host C libraries.  The difference in behaviour presumably lies in the C libraries.  But you can check this all for yourself by looking at the relevant version of the OpenJDK codebase.

---

Either way, the simple solution is probably to just fix the bad IP address.  (I suppose, you *could* implement your own Java-side DNS service provider that specifically checked for malformed IP addresses before doing the DNS lookup, but it probably isn't worth the effort.)

Comment: I have tested it on same java version. But if I see the exception stack, It is failing at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method).So this native method is not specific to platform?